# menu_navigation_links drupal is not returning the menu tree

Tags: drupal

I have created a custom menu in Drupal 6.3 and when I accessed the menu using the ***menu_navigation_links*** it is returning the result only for the home page but for other pages it is returning the empty.

Answer (score 0):

You must publish content if you want it to be visible in menu. That goes even for back-end, which is really strange. Also check on access rights. Is that hidden content accessible to user role you are using.